# Internet explorer connection is lost after 1 minute when using haproxy in between

Tags: rest, session, internet-explorer, timeout, haproxy

I have an angular client that calls a rest service deployed on an application server. Between the two stands a haproxy that forwards the requests coming from the client to the REST service. When using Internet explorer and the response time is greater than 1 minute, when the REST service returns, the response is not sent to the client. The client still waits for the response.

This seems to be a haproxy issue since when bypassing haproxy, the request returns as expected after ~3-4 minutes. 
I have tried all the different timeouts (client, server, http-request) but nothing seems to solve this.

My haproxy configuration can be found below:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    #log /dev/log    local1 notice
    #chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    #stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    tune.maxrewrite 1024
    tune.bufsize 32768

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
    #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3


defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option  log-separate-errors
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  1200s
    timeout server  1200s
    errorfile 400 /var/log/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /var/log/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /var/log/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /var/log/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /var/log/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /var/log/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /var/log/haproxy/errors/504.http

listen haproxy-monitoring
    bind *:1900
    mode http
    stats enable                                        # Enable satistics
    stats uri /haproxy?stats                            # Dashboard URL
    stats realm Strictly\ Private
    stats auth haproxyanalytics:haproxyanalytics              # Username / Password
    stats hide-version                                  # Hide the version of HAProxy used




# APACHE web servers
    #frontend haproxy-apache
    #    bind *:8001 transparent
    #    mode http
    #    default_backend apache-nodes

frontend http-in
    bind *:80 transparent
    acl has_special_uri path_beg /cxf
    use_backend rest-service if has_special_uri
    default_backend apache-web

backend apache-web
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor                                               # ensures the forwarded request includes the actual client IP address
    option httpclose
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    #option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost                # defines the check HAProxy uses to test if a web server is still valid for forwarding requests
    server "apache-1" ${CURRENT_NODE_IP}:${APACHE_PORT} check


backend rest-service
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor                                               # ensures the forwarded request includes the actual client IP address
    option httpclose
    option accept-invalid-http-request
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    #option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost                # defines the check HAProxy uses to test if a web server is still valid for forwarding requests
    server "karaf-1" ${CURRENT_NODE_IP}:${KARAF_REST_PORT} check
```

Comment: Please refer to [this article](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-logging/) and [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-http-load-balancing-on-an-ubuntu-vps#configure-logging-for-haproxy) to collect the haproxy log, then based on the log information to analyze the issue.

Comment: Still having this issue with HAProxy 2.1.7. The request is logged in haproxy when the response returns but the request on the browser console is still loading until it times out. When I then re-issue the request, because the response is cached it returns normally as expected. So it seems there is some session that expires???

This is an issue with Safari and Mozilla also. Only Chrome waits for the response as expected. Any ideas?